# Using for loop to create JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest

I am trying to create a JSON object like this:

```
"results": [
{"key":"1","trackname":"graham@insideoutrenovations.com.au"},
{"key":"1","trackname":"sjwindsor@westnet.com.au"},
]
```

However my PHP code is creating a new object for each iteration, the json looks like this:

```
0: "{"key":"1","trackname":"graham@insideoutrenovations.com.au"}"
1: "{"key":"1","trackname":"sjwindsor@westnet.com.au"}"
```

Here is my php:

```
$results = array();

function json_response($trackName) {
return json_encode(array(
    'key' => '1',
    'trackname' => $trackName
));
}

//There is 3 reg expressions for each primary array so we need to iterate by 3, otherwise we will get 3 lots of the same email address
for ($i = 0; $i < $numMatches; $i = $i + $patternNum) {
    $results[] = json_response($matches[0][$i]);
}
//$results = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$results);
echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the first json_encode function

you can either try to create associative array or use function compact, that will do the work for you.

```
//There is 3 reg expressions for each primary array so we need to iterate by   3, otherwise we will get 3 lots of the same email address
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numMatches; $i = $i + $patternNum) {
    $results[] = $matches[0][$i]; // json_encode removed
}

echo json_encode(array('results' => $results));
// or
echo json_encode(compact('results'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In final `echo` you encode in json an array already encoded.

Remove `json_encode` from `json_response` function.